# How to control formatting of pipe format tables in bookdown, such as striping?

Tags: rstudio, knitr, bookdown, kable

Many thanks to Rstudio for the visual Rmarkdown editor.  I am using it to generate and preview bookdown content.  When I insert a table, it generates a pipe format table.  However I want to remove the alternate row shading which kable does by default.  There is plenty of documentation on using function kable_styling but I cannot use that - there is no object for the table, it is autogenerated in the visual editor.  I don't really want to load it into a dataframe - that seems the wrong route.

How can I switch off row shading for pipe format tables globally or more generally modify the options for tables generated in this way via the visual Rmarkdown editor or otherwise?

A minimal section of my table looks like this.  When I knit it in Rstudio as a Rmarkdown document it appears unstriped.  I would like it stripe-free in bookdown, and ideally to control other styling of it.

```
+------------------+------------+
| $A=\pi.r^2$      | 1          |
+------------------+------------+
| $\sqrt{b^2-4ac}$ | 2          |
+------------------+------------+
| $\sum{1/i}$      | 3          |
+------------------+------------+
```

Many thanks.